# Simple first-order linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It's been a while since I covered DE's and somehow I can't solve the following using the general procedure that I found online:

$$ y' = \frac{4}{3}y - 4 $$

To find a particular solution, I can equate $-4$ to $P(x)=Bx+C$, which would yield $P(x)=-4$. Then, I use the general solution $y(x)=Ae^{ax}+P(x)$, which would yield me:

$$ y(x) =Ae^{ax}-4  $$

Given no initial value, I am not sure whether this would be correct.

Is it correct? If not, what did I do wrong?

Comment: You can check yourself whether or not it is correct. Given your $y(x)$, what are $\frac{\partial y(x)}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{4}{3}y(x) - 4$?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I did that, but it seemed incorrect because the recursion failed. I got $\frac{4}{3} \times 4 - 4$ for the constant part, which is $\frac{4}{3} \ne 0$, as would be expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the general form of first order liner D.E
$$y'+P(x)y=Q(x)$$
so that $P(x)=-\frac{4}{3}$ and $Q(x)=-4$
$$\rho=e^{\int P(x)dx}=e^{-\frac{4}{3}x}$$
$$\rho.y=\int \rho Q(x)dx=\int e^{-\frac{4}{3}x}(-4)dx=3e^{-\frac{4}{3}x}+C$$
hence 
$$y=3+Ce^{\frac{4}{3}x}$$